# Have Rush add dev dependencies to new project

Tags: rush

When [adding a new project](https://rushjs.io/pages/maintainer/add_to_repo/) to a Rush monorepo, is there a way for Rush to automatically insert the dev dependencies into the `package.json`? For example I want to use the same test frameworks between projects so it would be good to have Rush sync the dev dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this. `rush` has no idea which package requires which dependencies and, as such, you'll need to add them manually to each.

However, once you've configured your package.json's accordingly, `rush` will help you maintain dependency versioning across your monorepo. The precise behaviour can be configured by:

- setting `preferredVersions` in the [common-versions.json](https://rushjs.io/pages/configs/common-versions_json/) file
- using a [version policy](https://rushjs.io/pages/configs/version-policies_json/) such as `lockStepVersion`

Answer (score 2):

(I presume you found this answer already but in case any stumbles across this in the future)

If you run `rush add -h` you get the usage.
[usage: rush add [-h] -p PACKAGE [--exact] [--caret] [--dev] [-m] [-s] [--all]]

--dev                 If specified, the package will be added to the
"devDependencies" section of the package.json

The command you are looking for is

`rush add -p PACKAGENAME --dev`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm wanting Rush to `automatically insert the dev dependencies`. If I have to add the packages myself then that's not the solution I'm after.